# Custom metabox for file upload return empty filename

Tags: metabox

I want to attach a file to a post and "do something with it later". The file isn't being pulled over when I publish/update my post, the error I get is an empty filename. If I change the input type to text and submit I can get the text to save/display but trying to upload the file acts as though I haven't supplied the file to the form:

form --

function display_file_upload_meta_box($post_id,$post){

```
wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'file_upload_meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>
        <p>
            <?php
                $fileUpload= get_post_meta($object->ID,'file-upload-meta',true);
                if(!$fileUpload)
                    $fileUpload = '';
                echo 'file: '.$fileUpload;
            ?>
            <label for="file_upload_meta">Attach a file to this post</label>
            <input type="file" id="file_upload_meta" name="file_upload_meta" class="widefat"/>
        </p>
    <?php
    }
```

code to upload file --

```
$new_meta_value = wp_upload_bits($_FILES["file_upload_meta"]['name'], null, file_get_contents($_FILES["file_upload_meta"]['tmp_name']));
```

Comment: Does your form have an `enctype`?

Comment: Instead of using a file type input you can use the wordpress media library to upload file to post in a metabox, It would be easier to track the list of images via media library

Comment: I just need them to upload a single pdf when needed.